# C# Targeting a directory of which a mapname is partially known

Tags: c#, directory, temp

I am trying to send a file using the smtp from gmail, but I have stumbled upon a problem.

The file will be stored in the windows appdata folder.
To add the file to the e-mail, I'm using:

```
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment((Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/result.txt"));
```

The code as above works, BUT:

The issue I currently have, is that `Folder2` as seen above, will be a random name containing numbers, letters, and the word `TEMP`.

For example `a12TEMP34b`

I have tried and searched if I'm able to use `*` somehow, but can't seem to get it working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Directory.EnumerateDirectories to search for a specific folder :

```
var folder1 = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Folder1");
var folder2 = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folder1, "*TEMP*").Single();
var path = Path.Combine(folder2, "Folder3/result.txt");
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is indeed what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You could parse [Directory.GetDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) into a string array and grab the first element of that array if you're sure it will always be that path.

So:

```
string staticPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "/Folder1/";

string dynamicFolder = Directory.GetDirectory(staticPath, "*TEMP*")[0];

string finalPath = dynamicFolder + "/Folder3/result.txt"
```